# Linear transformation - linear matrix & kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

I have a problem understanding getting the KERNEL and IMAGE of a linear transformation. We have the following transformation given: 
$$ \mathbb{R}_{2}[ x ] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{2}[ x ] $$
$$ (\phi (p))(x) = (x p(x+1))' - 2p(x) $$

We first have to find its matrix in basis $$ \{ 1, x, x^2 \} $$
which I know how to get. The transformation matrix result is:

$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1& 1& 1\\ 
 0&  0& 4\\ 
 0&  0& 1
\end{bmatrix}
 $$

How do I get the KERNEL and the IMAGE from it ?

Would really appretiate an explanation, not just the result.

THANKS !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is generated by vectors that have the columns of the matrix as coordinates. Therefore the image is generated by $1$ and $1+4x+x^2$. These vectors are also linearly independent, so they form a basis.

The kernel is the set of vectors whose coordinates $X$ solve $MX=0$, where $M$ is the matrix.

Solving the system you get that the kernel is formed by vectors with coordinates $(a,a,0)$, thus a basis for the Kernel is the vector $1+x$.

Comment: Aha thanks I got the image part, but I still don't understand how you get the kernel. Can you be more detailed please ?

Comment: Which part you don't understand?

Comment: do you know the definition of kernel?

Comment: and what the matrix associated to a base does?

Comment: Solving the system part :).

Comment: $MX=0$. which are the solotions

Comment: the system reads $-x+y+z=0, 4z=0, z=0$ which are the solutions?

Comment: the set of vectors $(x,y,z)$ such that $z=0$ and $x=y$

Comment: so the set of vectors of the form $(a,a,0)$

Comment: where did you get the 4z = z ? aha ok i see you edited sorry

Answer (score 0):

To find the kernel just solve the homogeneous system

> $$ AX=0,\quad X = [x_1,x_2,x_3]^T. $$

The image is the space spanned by the column vectors of $A$.